# Why the QWebView does not execute the script on this webpage?

Tags: qt, qt4

Here is the code from the MainWindow constructor:

```
view = new QWebView(this);
view->load(QUrl("http://checkusernames.com/"));
```

The page loads fine and there is a script on that page which is supposed to be executed when the "Check User Name" button is clicked. It executes fine in IE and FireFox, but in the QWebView nothing happens.
My question is: Why this script is not executed in the QWebView?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? My suggestion is to enable web inspector and then use it to track the application logic (on that site)?

Comment: Check if `WebAttribute` `JavascriptEnabled` is set to true

Comment: Kamil, JavascriptEnabled is set to true.

Comment: Ariya, thank you for the hint about Web Inspector. I didn't know it existed... :) However I'm still not able to find the problem. I've not used JavaScript, but the one on the page looks OK to me. And the fact that it works on other browsers, tells me the problem is not in the script, but still I may be wrong...

Comment: Looking at the website, it seems that you have to wait for a series of async ajax calls to complete after you search a username. If it's just username searching you're interested in, why not call the php web service directly? It looks rather simple to make a call to the web service. All that you'd need to do is provide the timestamp in milliseconds as a parameter, the username, and the social networking site.

Comment: Thank you Cameron, for the suggestion, but I'm not interested in username searching. I just want to know why the script is not executed when you manually click on the button on that page? As i mentioned above everything works fine in IE and FF, but not in the QWebView.